# No route matches [GET] error in feature spec for update button routed to PUT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm writing a feature test for a Rails 7 application. I'm using RSpec, Capybara, and Capybara-Webkit.

The feature I'm testing archives a record(a developer app) when the user clicks an 'Archive' button. The action uses a PUT method. It all works in the browser, but when I run my test, the test is trying to use a GET to hit this path and errors out when it can't find the route.

If I change the route to use GET, the test runs fine, but this wouldn't be the correct method to use for updating a record to be archived.

Why would the click event in the test use a GET instead of a PUT?

```
Failure/Error: raise ActionController::RoutingError, "No route matches [#{env['REQUEST_METHOD']}] #{env['PATH_INFO'].inspect}"
 
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [GET] "/developer_apps/1/archive"
```

My spec:

```
scenario "can archive their developer app", js: true do
  visit developer_app_path(@developer_app)
  click_on 'Archive'
                    
  expect(page).to have_content "Developer app archived"
  expect(page).to have_content "Status: Archived"
end
```

The button in the view:

```
<%= link_to "Archive", archive_developer_app_path(@developer_app), class: 'btn btn-danger', data: { "turbo-method": :put, turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

The route:

```
put '/developer_apps/:id/archive', to: 'developer_apps#archive', as: :archive_developer_app
```

Comment: Probably JS is not used in your test

Comment: First, any Capy related stuff in your `spec_helper.rb`? Second, throw a `raise Capybara.current_driver` into your test to see what that is.

Comment: Indeed removing `js: true` solved it. Strange because I didn't have that in my test originally. My test was failing to get by the alert prompt confirming archiving and while researching a solution, I had come across solutions including `js: true` so I included it. Anyway, something else must have changed because it works now and the test passes. Thank you!